# MVC throws HttpCompileException when using Html.Raw(model.StringProperty)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, lucene.net

I have a VERY simple view on my MVC2 application that is responsible for displaying results from a Lucene search; one of whose properties includes the search item's summary.

At the moment, I've resorted to using new HtmlString(myString) as shown below:

```
<ul>
    <% foreach (var Item in Model)
       {  %>
    <li>
        <h4><%: Item.Title %></h4>
        <p><%: new HtmlString(Item.Summary) %></p>
        <a href="<%: Item.Url %>"><%: Item.Url %></a>
    </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

What I'd feel happier about using is

```
<ul>
    <% foreach (var Item in Model)
       {  %>
    <li>
        <h4><%: Item.Title %></h4>
        <p><%: Html.Raw(Item.Summary) %></p>
        <a href="<%: Item.Url %>"><%: Item.Url %></a>
    </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

However whenever I use Html.Raw(myString), I get an HttpCompileException with the following detais:

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper>'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'Raw' and no extension method 'Raw'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper>'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

What could be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.Raw` is new in ASP.NET MVC 3 (source: [ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/announcing-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate-2.aspx)), so you won't be able to use it in ASP.NET MVC 2.

Comment: Ah. Well that answers that, then doesn't it. Thanks.